# Array of character with non-printable characters in Julia

Tags: julia, non-printing-characters

I want to create an array of chars where some of the values are non-printable characters but not spaces:
I tried:

```
a = ['a', 'b', \n]
a = ['a', 'b', '']
a = ['a', 'b', nothing]
```

without success.

Comment: Try changing `a = ['a', 'b', \n]` to `a = ['a', 'b', '\n']`.  Beyond that, what non-printable characters do you seek to include ?

Comment: I want simply to create an array of length 3 but where one of the values is invisible (not a space)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? What is "visible" depends on printing. If you include something like a zero-width non-joiner, `\u200c`, it will still show _as the element of the array_. OTOH, if you `join` the array and `print` it, it will not be visible -- but so won't a newline, except for the fact that it starts a new line. Could you explain you actual goal?

Comment: I have two arrays of chars: `A = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `B = ['d', 'e']`. I want that both arrays have the same length (r) but I can't use `rpad` or `lpad` with spaces. The third value of `B` should be non-printable making both arrays have the same length.

Comment: I guess something like `["d", "e", ""]` _might_ behave how you want, but it's really hard to tell.

Comment: @MattB.The problem is that I have an array of characters and not an array of strings. But I think I managed this problem with the '\n' solution.